# '\n' being removed from Input field

Tags: javascript, textarea, line-breaks, html-input

I am working on dynamic form where I have input and select tag.

1. enter data and submit.
2. see entered information on sidebar `with edit button`
3. on `edit button` click : `form will render with value`s
4. edit data and click on update button to update

what exactly happening :

**While click on Edit button :** step num. 3  : if input field has data like

```
I am in first line 
I am in second line
I am in third line
```

It rendering on form like in step 3 :

```
I am in first lineI am in second lineI am in third line
```

Question : 
1. Does Input field not allowed new line?
2. If yes, I tried : `style="white-space: pre-line; white-space: pre-wrap;"` , but not working
3.How to stop being removed '\n' in input field?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `<textarea>`element? `<input>` has a limitation: "A single-line text field. Line-breaks are automatically removed from the input value." (MDN)

Comment: Use a `<textarea>` instead?

Comment: No, I want solution using <input>

Comment: input text element is for single line. For multiple line, textarea is the easiest option. Next best option is rolling your own text control.

Comment: Garr : How to create own text control?

Comment: you can use textarea and mess with the height in javascript/css. Rigging up input field for what is the whole reason the textarea exists seems over complicating a rather simple thing.

Comment: To create custom elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements

Comment: Can you post the code that renders the:       I am in first lineI am in second lineI am in third line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution using:

```
   // this is for textarea string 
var elementIdName = document.getElementById(key2);
key2Value = (elementIdName && elementIdName.tagName === "TEXTAREA") ?val.replace(/\\n/g, "<br />") : val;
```